# Combine two matrices with respect to primary key in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have two matrices with the first column being the primary key as shown below:

```
     | 123  3  234 11 |
     | 124  2  634 22 |
A  = | 125  8  731 33 |
     | 126  8  237 44 |
     | 127  6  235 55 |


     | 124  34  23 |
B  = | 125  45  73 |
     | 126  33  37 |
     | 127  44  25 |
```

I want the new matrix C such that

1. `find(A(:,2) > 5)`. In this case the indices that satisfy this condition 3,4
2. The primary key values for indices 3 and 4 in A in 125 and 126.
3. Find the rows having the values 125 and 126 in B which is 2,3.
4. Create the new matrix C concatinating the values in A and B with that primary key.

Matrix C should look like

```
C = | 125  8  731 33 45 73 |
    | 126  8  237 44 35 37 |
```

How can I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure your answer is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your key function to use is [ISMEMBER](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/ismember.html). Use two output indices:

```
[idxa, idxb] = ismember(a(:,1), b(:,1));
idxb(idxb==0) = [];
```

Then you can combine

```
c = [a(idxa,:) b(idxb,:)];
```

I hope you can add filters and select the columns you need by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The statistics toolbox contains a function called JOIN that basically does what you want.

http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/stats/dataset.join.html

I think it does what you are looking for. Does it?